# extract json array based on index in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

There are 2 queries. First is how to get the index of a json array

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(JSON_SEARCH(somecolumn1, 'one', 'macro', null, 
'$.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters'),"[",-1),']',1)
as name FROM table1;
```

Second is to get nth element(below extracts 2nd element) from json array

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(somecolumn1,"$.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters[1]") 
as name from table1;
```

I need to combine these 2 queries in a single command. First get the index and pass the index in JSON EXTRACT in nth position.

Comment: Provide a fiddle and show desired result for it. *get the index and pass the index in JSON EXTRACT in nth position.* CONCAT seems to be enough.

Comment: If you can please let us know your expected output..

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: If the entire array is something like below

[{
 "filter_name": "somefilter1",
 "filter_comm": []
}, {
 
 "filter_name": "macro",
 "filter_comm": "macro"
}, {
 
 "filter_name": "somefilter3",
 "filter_comm": []
}]

then $.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters[1] would give

{
 "filter_name": "macro",
 "filter_comm": "macro"
}

instead of 1 in value it should pass the 1st query 'SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(JSON_SEARCH(somecolumn1, 'one', 'macro', null, 
'$.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters'),"[",-1),']',1)
as name FROM table1'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(
    @`json`,
    CONCAT(
      '$.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters[',
      (
        SELECT
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              JSON_SEARCH(
                @`json`,
                'one',
                'macro',
                null,
                '$.my_policies.inmy_policies.some_filters[*].filter_name'
              ),
              "[",
              -1
            ),
            ']',
             1
          )
      ),
      ']'
    )
  ) `json_filter`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d263492f80367260240d8c6d12543bf3).